# how to echo a hyperlink in a html table via php

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to put together a table that would have one  show a hyperlink based on the ID in the database. I can not figure out the proper arrangement to get it working.
What am I doing wrong?

```php
<?php 
    $sqlactive= "SELECT * from Tabule1 WHERE TabStatus LIKE '0'";
    $result = $conn->query($sqlactive);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while ($row = $result-> fetch_assoc()) {
            echo "<tr>
            <td>" . $row["TabKlient"] . "</td>
            <td>" . $row["TabOsoba"] . "</td>
            <td>" . $row["TabItem"] . "</td>
            <td>" . $row["TabQty"] . "</td>
            <td>" . $row["TabNote"] . "</td>
            <td>" . $row["TabAddedBy"] . "</td>
            <td>" . $row["TabDate"] . "</td>"
            '<td><a href="edit.php?id='.$row['ID'].'"> test </a></td>' "</tr>";
          }
    }
?>
```

Comment: I do not understand the question. please post a example of what you want to achieve.

Comment: You are messing up the syntax, by following `"</td>"` right away with `'<td> …` – those are two text literals using different delimiters (double vs single quotes), but you have nothing concatenating them in between those. And the ending of that line does not make sense either, there you try to delimit the text literal you started with a single quote, with a double one, that does not match up either.

Comment: This is basic stuff you should be learning from some beginner tutorials and reading up on the basics of the syntax in the manual, rather than ask about here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your code syntax doesn't seem ok.

Please have a look at your syntax and try

Here is the corrected php code I fixed for you

```
<?php 
$sqlactive= "SELECT * from Tabule1 WHERE TabStatus LIKE '0'";
$result = $conn->query($sqlactive);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while ($row = $result-> fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<tr>
            <td>" . $row["TabKlient"] . "</td>
            <td>" . $row["TabOsoba"] . "</td>
            <td>" . $row["TabItem"] . "</td>
            <td>" . $row["TabQty"] . "</td>
            <td>" . $row["TabNote"] . "</td>
            <td>" . $row["TabAddedBy"] . "</td>
            <td>" . $row["TabDate"] . "</td>" . // <--- notice the dot here
            '<td><a href="edit.php?id='.$row['ID'].'"> test </a></td>' . /* <-- another dot here */ "</tr>";
    }
}
```